# Mixed up keys on a Scandinavian keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm using a Lenovo T14 with Ubuntu 20.04 and an external Logitech K850 wireless keyboard. The keyboard has a Scandinavian (Finnish/Swedish) layout. Everything worked fine until yesterday. I can't think of any triggering event for the issue. I thought I might've updated Ubuntu, but looking at the dates in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, they don't really coincide.

The built-in keyboard with roughly the same layout seems to work fine while some of the external keyboard's keys are misbehaving in a way that is very annoying for a programmer.

Details about the keyboard behaviour:

- Alt Gr + 2 which I expect to write an @-sign instead opens the second choice from the quick access bar to the left
- Left Super button seems to do what left Alt should. It, for example, toggles the menu bar at the top and I can start terminal with Ctrl + Super + T.
- Left Alt has taken the role of a Super button. Pressing left Alt opens the "app menu" and let's me search for stuff.
- Right Ctrl thinks it's Alt Gr. It lets me write an @-sign.
- Scandinavian letters work as they should: åöä
- The lesser than / greater than / pipe button in the lower left corner next to left Shift has switched places the §/½ button that's physically in the upper left corner before the row of numbers.
- Pressing Home moves the active window to the left side of the screen. Pressing End does the same, but to the right.

What I've tried so far based on either own reasoning or random Google advice:

- Reconfiguring the keyboard in Settings > Language and Region > Input sources. I've tried both Finnish and Swedish layouts.
- Resetting the shortcuts in Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts.
- Reconfiguring the keyboard layout with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
- Removing `~/.config/dconf/user`
- Removing `~/.config/monitors.xml`
- `gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1` shows roughly the right keyboard layout, but when pressing buttons, the mixed up functions are reflected. If I say lesser than, the on-screen keyboard shows me pressing the section-sign etc.
- Testing the keyboard out in `xkeycaps`. It shows me the same mixup I described above. `xkeycaps` does however give the following error when starting it up:

> A keyboard type was not specified. Based on the vendor identification string of the display ":0", which is "The X.Org Foundation" we will assume that you are using a keyboard of type "PC105".

Here's my `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBLAYOUT="fi"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

I think it used to say `Logitech` where it now says `pc105` before I manually edited the file.

After changing any keyboard parameters, I've either restarted the OS or run one or both of the following commands:

- `service keyboard-setup restart`
- `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`

Update 1:

I did some further testing now that I have some necessary hardware available.

1. I tried unpairing and pairing my current keyboard with `ltunify`. Issue persists.
2. I tested a corded USB keyboard. No problems.
3. I tested another Logitech wireless keyboard that I paired with `ltunify`. Also no issue.

So at some level the issue seems to be related to this particular keyboard specimen or model. Updated the model in the beginning of this question.

Update 2:
Tested `setxkbmap -layout fi`: no change

Checked if I could update the Unifying Receiver with:

```
fwupdmgr refresh && fwupdmgr get-updates
fwupdmgr update
```

No updates available. I have the following software versions for the receiver:

```
Firmware version: 012.010.00032
Bootloader version: BL.002.015
```

Comment: How about running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` again and select Logitech as the model.

Comment: I tried that with a couple of different variations of the choices provided. Issue remains the same. It changes the values in `/etc/default/keyboard`, but to no effect.

Comment: You should reboot after such a change. But maybe you did that.

Comment: Yeah. Rebooted. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I had the same exact issue, just appeared from nowhere. Tried many of the same steps you described but with no change. Connecting via bluetooth solved it for me but I would rather get the unifying receiver to work like before..